# Making the database and data access versions equal

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-access-layer, sql-scripts

There is a database and a data access layer(DAL) they are dependent on eachother.

Whenever the portal starts I need to automatically run a script that checks to see if there has been a change in the one or the other. If the versions are the same, the portal works. If not then it fails.

I need a solution to this problem

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Where did this portal came from? What is it and where will it lead us?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM like [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or a micro ORM like [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/). It allows you to regenerate your data access layer when you make changes in the database.